# Extending WCF proxy with partial classes and OnDeserializing: OnDeserializing does not get fired

Tags: wcf, proxy, deserialization, partial-classes

I'm trying to get OnDeserializing work with my WCF Proxy by using partial classes, but for some reason the OnDeserializing doesn't get triggered. In OnDeserialing I need to examine whether the web service returned nothing and set my own default value in that case. Everything looks OK in Visual Studio 2010 and I can access the properties of my WCF proxy in the code editor but at run-time OnDeserialing is never called. Can you please advice me what I'm doing wrong? Here's the code:

Proxy class

```
public partial class SerialInfo : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=2)]
    public string Location {
        get {
            return this.locationField;
        }
        set {
            this.locationField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("Location");
        }
    }
```

}

Extended proxy class

```
public partial class SerialInfo
{
[OnDeserializing]
void OnDeserializing(StreamingContext c)
{
  Location = "Test value";
  MessageBox.Show("OnDeserializing was triggered!");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding brackets to your attribute, and changing the method name

```
[OnDeserializing()]
void OnDeserializingMethod(StreamingContext c)
{
  Location = "Test value";
  MessageBox.Show("OnDeserializing was triggered!");
}
```

EDIT: Also, shouldn't partial classes have identical inheritance? Are you sure your partial class is extending what you think it is?

Comment: Looks like the problem was caused by the fact that I wasn't using DataContractSerializer. OnDeserializing is only supported by DataContractSerializer.